# whats a good combination of versions for bootstrap, rails, and gems to get the Bootstrap layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I've been trying to make Bootstrap work with rails and have tried most combinations of the following:

```
ruby => ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]

rails => Rails 4.0.8

gem => 2.4.1

bootstrap-sass (3.2.0.1, 3.0.2.1, 2.3.2.0, 2.3.1.0)
compass (1.0.1)
compass-core (1.0.1)
high_voltage (2.2.1)
less (2.5.1)
less-rails (2.5.0)
libv8 (3.16.14.3)
railties (4.0.8)
sprockets (2.12.1, 2.11.0, 2.2.2)
sprockets-rails (2.1.3, 2.0.1)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.8)
```

What is the version combinations that seems to work for anyone?

Comment: What did you try and what did not work? The way I use bootstrap in Rails is by including the css and js files from a cdn, not sure what others are doing though.

Comment: The top header bar with the menu is not formatting as expected. The links to About, Contact Us etc - are showing up in blue font and vertically instead of being horizontally aligned neatly inside the header menu bar.

Comment: You've got to show us some code, this doesn't say anything.

Comment: Let the `bundler` handle it. If you don't know which version to specify in your Gemfile - don't specify any. Bundler is smart enough to pick a compatible. If it breaks - most likely it's a problem with your own view code, not a compatibility issue.

Comment: `twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.8)` and `bootstrap-sass (3.2.0.1)` sounds like a nonsensical combination. The former uses Bootstrap v2.3.1 and the latter uses Bootstrap v3.2.0, and Bootstrap v2 & v2 aren't compatible with each other.